# Adding a file upload to a Symfony2 form throws an "Entity was not found" and a session is active error

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony2 form that I want to add a file upload dialog to.

According to the Symfony docs (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), I have created a Document class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file;


    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
}
```

And a DocumentType form class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
                $builder
                        ->add('file')
                        ;
        }

        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                    'data_class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Document',
            ));
        }

        public function getName()
        {
                return 'document_form';
        }
}
```

However, when I add this to my existing entity and form class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Profile;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Acme\AppBundle\Entity\jDocument;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="UserProfile")
 */
class UserProfile extends GenericProfile
{

    //... Other entity params

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(cascade={"persist", "remove"}, targetEntity="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Document")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="picture_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="set null")
     */
    protected $picture;

    /**
     * Set picture
     *
     * @param Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Document $picture
     */
   //\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Document  
    public function setPicture($picture)
    {
        $this->picture = $picture;
    }

    /**
     * Get picture
     *
     * @return Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Document
     */
    public function getPicture()
    {
        return $this->picture;
    }

    //... Other entity getters and setters

}
```

Whenever I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /var/www/wolseley-integrated-services/builds/dev/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 421
```

But the **page title** is "Entity was not found. (500 Internal Server Error)".

Can anybody spot which entity it can't find? Or if that's even the issue?

I've done some googling and checked that session.auto_start is set to 0 in php.ini, I've cleared all my sessions and caches... I'm stumped!

Comment: Without more info it's really hard to say what went wrong. I suggest you go straight to `classes.php` and navigate to the line 421. You should probably get some hint whether entity is your problem or some thing else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was getting this strange session error message because of an error page definition in my nginx config.

The entity not found issue was resolved by correcting some errors in my entities.  The Symfony developer bar provided me with enough information to track the issue down.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and couldn't find which entity is not found. I also checked the developer bar couldn't realize which entity is failing. Can you please provide some information how to address the entity that is not found.

Comment: Sorry bateristt, the info I posted above is all I can really offer. I took a look at my entities in the debug bar, and some were showing errors. After I resolved the errors, the EntityNotFound error disappeared. Maybe you should create a new SO question detailing your problem and post it in the #symfony room on irc.freenode.net to get some of the Symfony gurus to look at it.